# Problem with the opencv library in python

Tags: python, opencv

This is my python script:
-def detect_corner(binary_map, intersections):

```
field_separation = np.copy(binary_map)

cv2.line(field_separation, (intersections[0][0],intersections[0][1]), (intersections[1][0],intersections[1][1]),0, 4)

contours = cv2.findContours(field_separation,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

print(contours)
#Find the greatest area contour

areas = []


for contour in contours:

    areas.append(cv2.contourArea(contour))

max_index = np.argmax(areas)
max_area = areas.pop(max_index)

remaining_area = sum(areas)

return (remaining_area/max_area)
```

This code works properly on another system but while I run it in my system, it shows the following error:

'cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:272: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea''

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing should be due to using code for an older version of the module.

I modified `findContours(...)[]`. This should solve your problem.

```
field_separation = np.copy(binary_map)

cv2.line(field_separation, (intersections[0][0],intersections[0][1]), (intersections[1][0],intersections[1][1]),0, 4)

contours = cv2.findContours(field_separation,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

print(contours)
#Find the greatest area contour

areas = []


for contour in contours:

    areas.append(cv2.contourArea(contour))

max_index = np.argmax(areas)
max_area = areas.pop(max_index)

remaining_area = sum(areas)

return (remaining_area/max_area)
```

If I was helpful to you I ask you to accept the answer as a solution (;

Happy Coding